# System.Security.Cryptography.Cng: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: c#, encryption, certificate, rsa, public-key-encryption

I used standard code to get this file encrypted. The certificate is not expired and the key is valid. I don't find the reason why it throws this exception.

```
        public byte[] EncryptDataOaepSha256(X509Certificate2 cert, byte[] data)
        {
            RSA rsa = cert.GetRSAPublicKey();

            if (rsa != null)
            {
                return rsa.Encrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
            }

           return null;
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXmjK.png)

Comment: The padding mode is not compatible with the certificate.

Comment: @jdweng i checked my certificate and its a indeed a other padding if i change it to SHA-1 i get the same error

Comment: Sha1 is 160 bits but your link is showing 256.  Do you want sha1 padded to 256?   The length of Sha1 hash is 40 hex characters gives us 20 bytes = 160

Comment: @jdweng i found that my certificate is sha256 sorry for the wrong input. 
I dont get what you mean ? I think that the size of my data is the problem but if i try them all i stil get this error

Comment: What is your project target?  No all encryption modes were support in Net. Microsoft finally decided in Net 4.7.2 to use the OS for TLS encryption.  You may be using an older version of Net where the encryption doesn't work.

Comment: @jdweng I saw that my data was too large to encrypt, so I needed a solution. I chose to encrypt my key. With this code, you can only encrypt 190 bytes.

Comment: If data is too large you can always break into smaller pieces.

Comment: @jdweng do you have a example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jdweng thanks for the code i fixed the problem to do this

```
   public byte[] EncryptDataOaepSha256(X509Certificate2 cert, byte[] data, ILogger log)
    {
        RSA rsa = cert.GetRSAPublicKey();
        byte[] input = data;
        long blocksize = 182;
        long byteCounterInt = 0;
        byte[] byteCounter = BitConverter.GetBytes(byteCounterInt);
        byte[] output = new byte[0];

        try
        {
            for (long i = 0; i < input.Length; i += blocksize)
            {
                long chunksize = (input.Length - i > blocksize) ? blocksize : input.Length - i;
                byte[] temp = new byte[chunksize];
                temp = temp.Concat(byteCounter).ToArray();
                Array.Copy(input, i, temp, 0, chunksize);
                byte[] encrypteByte = rsa.Encrypt(temp, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);

                if (output.Length > 0)
                {
                    output = output.Concat(encrypteByte).ToArray();
                }
                else
                {
                    output = encrypteByte;
                }
            }

            return output;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            log.LogCritical("Error encrypting a stream");
            log.LogCritical(e.Message);
            log.LogCritical(e.StackTrace);
            log.LogCritical(e.ToString());

            return null;
        }
    }

 public byte[] DecryptDataOaepSha256(X509Certificate2 cert, byte[] data, ILogger log)
    {
        RSA rsa = cert.GetRSAPublicKey();

        byte[] input = data;
        long blocksize = 190;
        long byteCounterInt = 0;
        byte[] byteCounter = BitConverter.GetBytes(byteCounterInt);
        byte[] output = new byte[0];

        try
        {
            for (long i = 0; i < input.Length; i += blocksize)
            {
                long chunksize = (input.Length - i > blocksize) ? blocksize : input.Length - i;
                byte[] temp = new byte[chunksize];
                Array.Copy(input, i, temp, 0, chunksize);
                byte[] tempMinBytecount = new byte[temp.Length - byteCounter.Length];
                Array.Copy(temp, byteCounter.Length, tempMinBytecount, 0, tempMinBytecount.Length);

                byte[] decrypteByte = rsa.Decrypt(tempMinBytecount, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);

                if (output.Length > 0)
                {
                    output = output.Concat(decrypteByte).ToArray();
                }
                else
                {
                    output = decrypteByte;
                }
            }

            return output;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.LogCritical("Error decrypting a stream");
            log.LogCritical(e.Message);
            log.LogCritical(e.StackTrace);
            log.LogCritical(e.ToString());

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: @jdweng only problem i have right now is that my dicription dont work :/. I get e length of the data to decrypt is not valid for the size of this key.
i used the same logic only dicrypt and use the private key

Comment: You need to add a byte count between each chunk when Concat().  Then when you decrypt you read the chunk size and extract each chunk based on the size.  When you encrypt the encrypt size is not the same number of bytes as the raw data.

Comment: @jdweng do you have a example off that solution.

Comment: Just add a 4 (int) or 8 byte (long) between  each block :  386  (386 bytes) 400 (400 bytes) 600 (600 bytes).  Use BitConverter.GetBytes(Number) and  BitConverter.ToInt32(byte[]) to do the conversion.

Comment: @jdweng you lost me there

Comment: You need to add either a 4 byte or 8 byte count before each piece when encrypting message.  Then when decrypting remove the byte count and then read the number of bytes.  The next next block when decrypting the beginning of data will have the byte count for next block.

Comment: @jdweng I stll get the same error check my code above

Comment: You need to put byte count inside for loop.  Each chunk needs the number.  If still fail put break point in encrypt for loop and get the count for each chunk.  Then do same in decrypt.  The counts should match.

Answer (score 0):

Try code like below to break array into smaller pieces

```
            byte[] input = null;
            long blocksize = 1000000;
            for(long i = 0; i < input.Length; i += blocksize)
            {
                long chunksize = (input.Length - i > blocksize) ? blocksize : input.Length - i;
                byte[] temp = new byte[chunksize];
                Array.Copy(input, i, temp, 0, chunksize);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the previous post, there is a small error in the code, which has been fixed.
Also, it has been changed from SHA256 to SHA512, which changes the block size. Therefore, the input is 382 bytes and the output is 512 bytes, which you should save.
Now your block is 512 bytes which are lined up.
To read from decrypt, well, you have to separate the 512-byte packet and check it.

for Encrypt

```
RSA? rsa = Certificate.GetRSAPublicKey();
byte[] input=data;
long blockSize = 382;
byte[] output = Array.Empty<byte>();
try {
    for (long i = 0; i < input.Length; i += blockSize)
    {
        long chunkSize = (input.Length - i > blockSize) ? blockSize : input.Length - i;
        byte[] temp = new byte[chunkSize];
        temp = temp.ToArray();
        Array.Copy(input, i, temp, 0, chunkSize);
        byte[] encryptedByte = rsa.Encrypt(temp, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA512);

        if (output.Length > 0)
            output = output.Concat(encryptedByte).ToArray();
        else
            output = encryptedByte;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    
}
```

for Decrypt

```
RSA? rsa = Certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
byte[] input=data;
long blockSize = 512;
byte[] output = Array.Empty<byte>();

try
{
    for (long i = 0; i < input.Length; i += blockSize)
    {
        long chunkSize = (input.Length - i > blockSize) ? blockSize : input.Length - i;
        byte[] temp = new byte[chunkSize];
        Array.Copy(input, i, temp, 0, chunkSize);

        byte[] encryptedByte = rsa.Decrypt(temp, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA512);

        if (output.Length > 0)
            output = output.Concat(encryptedByte).ToArray();
        else
            output = encryptedByte;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{}
```

use output for your reason.